# No se en que estoy fallando con este Do While

Tags: java, while

Saludos gente. Estoy empezando con Java y haciendo un ejercicio probando el do_while no se en que punto estoy fallando. La intención del bucle es que si el usuario mete un valor inferior a 1 o superior a 4 que el programa vuelva a pedir al usuario que vuelva a meter el valor.

Si le dejo así, al introducir un valor correcto debería volver a pedir que se introduzca el número pero por lo que parece, se corta el bucle.

La cuestión es que he probado y si solo dejo una condición en while me funciona bien pero al ponerle el && algo me falla.

¿Estoy fallando en algo o es que el while no puede contener multiples condiciones?

Gracias de antemano.

```
public class Act6_4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declaración de variables
    int estacion=50;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Empieza el bucle por si el usuario introduce un número fuera del rango de opciones
    do { 
        //Muestra mensaje en pantalla pidiendo al usuario que introduzca un número del 1 al 4
        System.out.println("Introduce número de estación (1 al 4)");
        estacion = teclado.nextInt();

        //Empieza la condición con varias opciones
        switch (estacion) {
            case 1: System.out.println("Verano");
                    break;
            case 2: System.out.println("Otoño");
                    break;  
            case 3: System.out.println("Invierno");
                    break;  
            case 4: System.out.println("Primavera");
                    break;  
        }
    }   while (estacion<=0 && estacion>=5);
}
```

}

Comment: Cambia tu && (condicion and) por una condicion or (||) ademas si quieres que sea con numeros superiores a 4 quedaria de esta manera -> while (estacion<=0 || estacion>4);

Comment: Tu mismo lo dices en tu descripción: *si el usuario mete un valor inferior a 1 __o__ superior a 4*. Es **o**, no **y**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución.
Respecto a lo de la segunda condición, pensaba que siempre tenían que tener dos carácteres. (>= <= o ==) aunque no se porque ^^u

Answer (score 0):

solo debes cambiar esta linea:

```
while (estacion>0 && estacion<5);
```

y cada vez que el valor que introduzcas este entre 0 y 5 seguirá realizando la iteracion pero cuando sea diferente terminara la misma.

Comment: lo acabo de probar y funciono correctamente. Creo que el puntaje negativo esta demas

Comment: Lo tienes al revés. OP dijo: *La intención del bucle es que si el usuario mete un valor inferior a 1 o superior a 4 que el programa vuelva a pedir al usuario que vuelva a meter el valor.*